# Change select background image based on option attribute

Tags: html, css, sass

I'm attempting to write some `SASS` that will alter the select box background image based on whats selected, but i'm not sure if its possible!

Heres how i'm attempting it, i'm putting the background image in a data attribute on the options like this

```
<select name="language_selector" id="language-selector">
  <option value="english" data-background-image="img/england.svg">English</option>
  <option value="spanish" selected data-background-image="img/spain.svg">Spanish</option>
</select>
```

Then i'm trying to use `SASS` to set the value of the select box based on the selected option like this

```
select {
 height: 45px;
 width: 300px;
 border-radius: 4px;
 font-family:$font;
 font-weight: 400;
 -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
 -webkit-appearance: none;
 -moz-appearance: none;
  appearance: none;
  padding-left: 40px;
  position:relative;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position-x: 10px;
  background-position-y: center;
  background-size: 18px;
  option:active ~ & {
     background-image:url(attr(data-background-image));
  }
 }
```

Is something like this possible? How would I get the value of the option attribute and apply it to the select box?

I know I can use Javascript for this, but the aim is to do this purely with CSS/SASS, not using any JS.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure, you would have to use something like

```
//pseudo sass
parent if child(with id='') has attribute selected {
  background-img: '.../.../...';
}
```

> but selecting parents depending on what children are inside is not
>   possible.. so have to use javascript.

```
 option:active ~ & {
     background-image:url(attr(data-background-image));
  }
```

like this you would only select the option itself what's probably not your goal right?

Comment: I'm really confused what you're doing in the first code snippet, can you explain?

Comment: its not really code its only what i expect you want to do.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
select
{
    option:checked ~ &{
         background-image:url(attr(data-background-image));
   }
}
```

Comment: Can you expand upon this answer a little bit to explain to the OP why you are using these operators and how it achieves the goal (if it does)? This will help not just the OP but others who find this question/answer later and who can benefit from it.